# JavaFX Callback implementation of call method with lambda

Tags: java, javafx, lambda

I found really nice piece of code here: [blog](http://blog.ngopal.com.np/2011/10/19/dyanmic-tableview-data-from-database/)

I want to implement it in my application. This blog post is from 2014 and author didn't used lambda. I tried to do it by myself, to avoid really ugly annonymous call, but I can't figure out, how to do it. There is original code:

```
tableColumn.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) {
                        return new SimpleStringProperty((param.getValue().get(j).toString()));
                    }
                });
```

And Intellij automatically converts it to:

```
tableColumn.setCellValueFactory(param -> 
new SimpleStringProperty((param.getValue().get(j).toString())));
```

But there is an error:

```
Cannot resolve method getValue()
```

on "param". I've changed it a little to:

```
tableColumn.setCellValueFactory((TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) -> 
new SimpleStringProperty((param.getValue().get(j).toString())));
```

And it's not working because of that:

```
Incompatible parameter types in lambda expression: 
expected object but found CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String>
```

I've been looking around how to fix it, but unfortunelly I couldn't find simple answer.

Comment: How is your `TableColumn` declared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very probably using a raw `TableColumn` instance.
While `TableColumn` is a generic class declared as `TableColumn<S,T>` where

> S - Th type of the TableView generic type (i.e. S == TableView)
>
> T - The type of the content in all cells in this TableColumn.

So when you write :

```
col.setCellValueFactory(
        (param->new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j).toString())));
```

`param` is considered by the compiler as a variable declared with the `Object` class and `Object` don't have of course a `getValue()` method.
Whereas the compilation error :

> Cannot resolve method getValue()

Declare a parameterized/generic`TableColumn` instance  and it should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem. Changing that to correct generic types instead of raw gave me headache, but finally it's working without single warning and with pretty lambda :)

Comment: You are welcome. Raw types are really bad with us ;-)